# Solve algebraic equation in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve simple algebraic parametrized equation `sqrt(x)=sqrt(a)+1` with SymPy command `solveset`:

```
x, a = symbols("x a")
solveset(Eq(sqrt(x), sqrt(a)+1), x)
```

It returns as part of answer (conditional set) two solutions: `2*sqrt(a)+a+1` and `-2*sqrt(a)+a+1`. I can't understand how we can obtain the second one with minus sign  from our equation!

Command `solve` in the same time gives us only solution `(sqrt(a) + 1)**2`, which is correct in my opinion.

What happens with `solveset`, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is to do with the sets you are solving over. Specifically, `solveset` defaults to a complex domain, resulting in extraneous solutions due to the complex square root. But by explicitly specifying a real domain and defining `a` and `x` to both be positive (as we're just dealing with reals, so can't have `a` or `x` negative), the desired solution can be extracted:

```py
x, a = symbols('x a', positive=True)
solveset(Eq(sqrt(x), sqrt(a) + 1), x, domain=S.Reals).as_relational(x).expand()
# x = 2⋅√a + a + 1
```

Comment: Can you give me example of complex `x` and `a`, for which `-2*sqrt(a)+a+1` is a solution of the given equation? When I replace manually `x` by  `-2*sqrt(a)+a+1` in this equation, I get `abs(sqrt(a)-1)=sqrt(a)+1`, which is correct iff `a=0`.

Comment: @nickme Sure, consider `a = 3+4i`. The complex square root of `a` is then 2+i or -2-i. With `sqrt(a) = -2 - i` we have `sqrt(x) = - i - 1` so `x = 2i`. Now consider the extra solution `x = -2 * sqrt(a) + a + 1`, which is satisfied when `sqrt(a) = 2 + i` and `x = 2i`. The issue with the multivaluedness of `sqrt(a)` disappears when using just the reals because the negative branch is excluded by convention. Also if the principal square root were used by `sympy.solveset` (like elsewhere) the behaviour would be as you'd expect, but that's not what happens, thus necessitating restricting the domain.

Comment: But `solveset` for `a = 3+4*I` gives for the equation `sqrt(x)=sqrt(a)+1` only one solution `x=8+6*I`! Why?

Comment: I think most likely due to the multivaluedness of `sqrt` in `sympy.solveset` not being universal — if you directly evaluate `sqrt(3 + 4*I)` you'll see it'll only give the principal root, which is why plugging in a concrete value will give you a solution set which uses just the principal square root. The inconsistency in the treatment of `sqrt(a)` for complex a (either multivalued or singled valued) is the root cause of this. All I can really explain is how it seems solveset got that extra solution, but exactly why there's inconsistency I don't know right now.

Comment: Square root is multivalued but square is not. If `sqrt(x)=sqrt(a)+1` then `x = (sqrt(a)+1)**2`. So I don't understand, where multivaluedness of `sqrt` here is used?!

Answer (score 0):

The method that `solveset` uses gives two roots to consider but `checksol` is not able to show that the 2nd solution is not generally valid so to be safe, it returns both and shows you the condition which must be checked. If you substitute a value in for `a` you will obtain a set with the single concrete answer.

Comment: I just cannot think of for what value of `a` the second expression will be the root of this equation.

Comment: What about `a=0`? But this is a moot point, I think, because in the current version of SymPy the offending expression does not appear in the ConditionSet.

Comment: With `a=0` both roots are equal to `1`, so we don't need 2nd solution even so.

Comment: Ah, yes. So a second solution should only be necessary if it gives additional information (which this doesn't). So update your version of SymPy, if possible, and you should only get the one solution.